# Problemas al codificar una variable en R

Tags: r

Quiero codificar una variable en 4 categorías. Sé que debo usar la función `cut`, pero por muchos ejemplos que miro no la entiendo.

La variable debería codificarla en 4 categorías:

- La primera categoría seria entre su minimo y el primer cuartil.
- La segunda entre el primer cuartil y el segundo.
- La tercera entre el segundo cuartil y el tercer cuartil.
- La cuarta entre el tercer cuartil y el cuarto cuartil.

Todas las categorías con intervalos de la forma `[A,B]` menos el primero que será `[Minimo,Q1]`.

No sé cómo hacerlo. Llevo dos días buscando, remirando y aparte no veo ejemplos parecidos.

Comment: Hola Willy,siempre es bueno poner el código de lo que has intenado hacer, para así saber que es lo que específicamente no estás haciendo bien ;).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utlizar la opción `include.lowest` de la función `cut`,

```
> datos = seq(1, 10)
> datos
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> categorías = cut(datos, breaks=quantile(datos), include.lowest=TRUE)
> categorías
 [1] [1,3.25]   [1,3.25]   [1,3.25]   (3.25,5.5] (3.25,5.5] (5.5,7.75]
 [7] (5.5,7.75] (7.75,10]  (7.75,10]  (7.75,10] 
Levels: [1,3.25] (3.25,5.5] (5.5,7.75] (7.75,10]

> table(categorías)
categorías
  [1,3.25] (3.25,5.5] (5.5,7.75]  (7.75,10] 
         3          2          2          3
```

*quantile*, genera los valores mínimo. máximo y los cuartiles.